# application crash when run on device with distribution profile

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I was develope one iphone app. run this app on device with developer profile it's work fine and not crash, but use distribution profile and run app on device, after sometime the application is crash. so, pls tell me what's the problem for app crash.

Comment: What kind of crash are you getting?

Comment: According to my opinion...App is not crashing...This happens every time when you are running with distribution profile...nothing issue..just run your app from iPhoe after crashing..

Comment: Try using developer profile...

Answer (score 3):

It's a known issue. You can't run apps signed with a distribution profile by running them from Xcode. They crash shortly after launch.

If you launch the app from the device after the crash, it should run fine.

Comment: This simply makes me want to kill people.  I want to upvote you 10 thousand times.  It's still an issue in 4.x.  But what's odd is that this works with another one of my applications.

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect some memory/threading issues since on the developer profile you run application in Debug mode, whereas Distribution defaults to Release. Provide us with the crash details and then we might be able to help.